# Log something at beginning & end of Django management commands

Tags: python, django, logging, command, django-management-command

Right now I have multiple management commands in my Django project.

I would like to log something like `[command_name] command started` and `[command_name] command finished` at the beginning and end of the commands in a way that I would'nt repeat myself in each command.

Already tried decorators on top of the `handle()` method but didn't think it was a good solution since I would have to decorate the `handle()` method in all commands.

PS: I'm using python logger.

### Edit

Got to this point:

```py
class Parent(BaseCommand):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info(f'started {self.__module__}')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.info(f'finished {self.__module__}')
```

Output:

```sh
> started command_name
> finished command_name
> actual command logs
```

Comment: Why not simply have your commands inherit from a common base class that will do this for you?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But how would I get the command name (from the inheriting class) to concat in the log?

Comment: `self.__module__` would give you the module name of the subclass.

Comment: That's the sequence of my `__init__`:

1. `logger.debug(f'started {self.__module__}')`
2. Call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`
3. `logger.debug(f'finished {self.__module__}'`

But somehow i'm getting this in the console:

1. started command_name
2. finished command_name
3. actual command logs (command is being executed here)

Comment: Don't override `__init__` that is called when the instance is created but it does not run the command in reality. Override `execute` instead like I do in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a base class which all of your commands shall inherit from and do the logging in it. As a good place to log the output is to override the `execute` method of the command (Your code logs in wrong order because the command is not actually run by the `__init__` method, it is actually called on the class separately using the `run_from_argv` method of the class):

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand as DjangoBaseCommand

class BaseCommand(DjangoBaseCommand):
    def execute(self, *args, **options):
        logger.info(f'started {self.__module__}')
        output = super().execute(*args, **options)
        logger.info(f'finished {self.__module__}')
        return output
```

Now for all of your commands simply inherit from this command:

```py
from some_app.somewhere import BaseCommand


class MyCommand(BaseCommand):
    # Your code here
```